# How to implement eles.CustomFunction() on Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Is this possible to extend defined library like **Cytoscape.js** with custom function to make attributiton, in o
anothoer js file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because yes it is.

Comment: @m3rt_ali What code have you tried?  What has you confused?  Generally, questions that can be answered "Yes/no, RTM" are not good candidates for SO.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask